# Return Empty Array instead of Null for In-Memory Collection

Tags: c#, ienumerable

When I use a method that return an `IEumerable`, First i check it for Null value and then check it for, Is there any Item.

```
public IEnumerable<Order> GetOrdersByServiceName(string serviceName)
{
     if (IsValidService(serviceName))
        return null;

     var orders = GetValidOrder(serviceName);

     return orders;
}
```

Usage:

```
var orders=GetOrdersByServiceName("TestService");

if(orders == null or !orders.any())
   //do something
```

If `GetOrdersByServiceName` return Null and I forget Null checking, Code will throw  Null Reference Exception at some condition.I want eliminate `orders == null` and just use `!orders.any()` in `If` statement.
I think two condition has same semantic and tell me result is *nothing* (Null Object pattern):

- !orders.any()
- orders == null

To realize that all Developer at my team  must make sure every method which return  IEnumerable , return `Enumerable.Empty() instead of Null value.

My Question Is: Are there any scenario that result of called method -Null or Empty Array- have different semantic for caller method?

Comment: `To realize that all Developer at my team must make sure every method which return IEnumerable , return Enumerable.Empty() instead of Null value.` Yes. They must not return `null`. LINQ methods will never return `null` - always `Enumerable.Empty` - you should do the same.

Comment: If you return `null` you're saying that the specified service is not valid. If you change that to return an empty Enumerable instead of null, then you've lost that information. However it seems to me that the code should be throwing an exception if the service is invalid.

Comment: I guess this is a bug: `if (IsValidService(serviceName)) return null`

Comment: change the implementation for GetValidOrder and GetOrdersByServiceName ! null daoesn't say what's wrong!

"**GetValidOrder**" should always return a list (or IEnumerable).

Here's the pattern I would follow:

    public IEnumerable<Order> GetOrdersByServiceName(string serviceName)
    {

         if (!IsValidService(serviceName))
          {
            throw new Exception("invalid servicename");
          }
    
         return GetValidOrder(serviceName);
   
    }